# How to maximize lung oxygen intake?

Tags: human-anatomy, breathing, lungs

What method of breathing provides a sudden surge of oxygen into the lungs filling it as full as possible in volume and density. Deep breaths? Shallow breaths? Breaths taken while bent over? Deep inhales followed by further inhales. Breaths held? Movement while breaths are held?

Comment: @WYSIWYG can't we just talk about it from a scientific perspective in abstract? assuming ease and procedure are a non-issues. of all the variant methods which is the most optimal and what makes it so.

Comment: @WYSIWYG what about this question will it work?

Comment: Don't quite understand why this is an off-topic. Anyway, the deep inhales with full exhales are the most effective when it comes to lung ventilation. This is because you have a so called 'dead space' - about 150 ml of air in your pathways (mouth, trachea, etc). So if you inhale 200 ml, only 50 ml will get its way to alveoli which is 25%. If you breath in 600 ml, 600-150=450 of air will get to the lungs which is 75%.

Comment: @ctapobep. The question was explicitly about usage of inhalers, which as per the site's policy is off topic (medical advice). This edit seems to be fine and can be reopened.

Comment: I don't see any question seeking medical advice here

Comment: The safest way to maximize oxygen intake is to do it slowly over a period of weeks to months using breathing exercises and aerobic anaerobic exercise combination. This will increase the hemoglobin concentration of blood leading to increased oxygen carrying capacity as well as capillary density of the muscles ensuring good oxygen supply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the oxygen concentration of inhaled air in the absence of an external source of oxygen. However, you can use your lungs at their maximum capacity doing this:

- **breathe deeply:** =increase tidal volume. Your muscles will inflate your lungs as much as they are able to, inflating parts of the lungs that were not fully inflated (atelectases) in the process. This also allows you to inhale a volume much greater than your physiologic dead space (volume of inhalation that does not participate in gas exchanges)
- **breathe to high enough frequency:** the faster you will want to expel $CO_2$ and replace it with room air, the higher frequency you will need to adopt.

Frequency and tidal volume are the two components of **minute ventilation** (= (frequency/minute) X tidal volume), which is the physiologic value you are working to increase.

**Position:** The upright position is best suited, since the weight of the lung tissue pulling downwards will facilitate inflation

**WARNING: using those techniques unsupervised can cause acute respiratory alkalosis, which is unhealthy and puts you in immediate danger.**

Comment: Actually, you are working to increase alveolar ventilation...